# Gstreamer pipeline in Opencv videoCapture()

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, video-capture, pipeline, gst-launch

I'm trying to open an IP camera in OpenCV using gstreamer pipleine. 
I can open the IPcamera using Gstreamer in terminal, using :

`gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.0.220:554/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=10" latency=10 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`

Now with this how can I open the same camera in OpenCV `videoCapture()`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy the same pipe and use it in VideoCapture (if you built OpenCV with gstreamer modules).

Important point is you need to finish the pipe with an `appsink` element.

```
const char* pipe =  "rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://192.168.0.220:554/user=admin&password=admin&channel=1&stream=0.sdp?real_stream--rtp-caching=10\" latency=10 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink";
VideoCapture cap(pipe);
```